# How to walk over assign inside (nested) functions? (What environment should I use?)

Tags: r, assign, tidyverse

**tl;dr / summary**

I have a function that takes a list with many elements as argument. I would like to be able to work with those elements directly by assigning them within the function. As I have many elements I would like to use the `walk` functions from the `tidyverse` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
list <- (a = 1, b = 2)
func <- function(x){
  walk2(names(x), x, assign, envir = {some environment})
  {Rest of the function, where I can use a and b instead of x$a and x$b}
}
```

What environment should I use? And no `parent.frame()` does **not** work, see below.

**Why parent.frame() doesn't work**

*Step 1: No functions* - Here parent.frame() is necessary (because you're using assign inside a function). But if you do, everything works fine.

```
x <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
a <- 0
b <- 0

# Doesn't work:

walk2(names(x), x, assign)
a
b

# Does work:

walk2(names(x), x, assign, envir = parent.frame())
a
b
```

*Step 2: One function* - Things get more complicated when you do the same inside a function. Using `parent.frame()` as environment will cause the variables to change in the global environment as well.

```
func <- function(x) {

  walk2(names(x), x, assign)
  print(paste0("a inside func without parent.frame() is ", a))
  print(paste0("b inside func without parent.frame() is ", b))

  walk2(names(x), x, assign, envir = parent.frame())
  print(paste0("a inside func with parent.frame() is ", a))
  print(paste0("b inside func with parent.frame() is ", b))

}

# Using envir = parent.frame() seems to work at first

x <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
a <- 0
b <- 0
func(x)

# But a and b get overwritten in the global environment as well (unwanted)

a
b
```

This is not desirable. This does not happen when you assign in a "normal" way as shown by the following example.

```
# How it should work

func_desired <- function(x){

  a <- x[[1]]
  b <- x[[2]]

  print(paste0("a inside func_alt is ", a))
  print(paste0("b inside func_alt is ", b))

}

# a and b are correctly assigned within the function

x <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
a <- 0
b <- 0
func_desired(x)

# But outside of the function a and b are not altered

a
b
```

*Step 3: Nested functions* - Here it becomes clear that using `parent.frame()` will assign the variables not in the environment where `walk` is called, but the one behind that.

```
func2 <- function(x){

  func(x)

  print(paste0("a inside func2 is ", a))
  print(paste0("b inside func2 is ", b))

}

# a and b are assigned 1 and 2 inside func2, 
# But in the global environment they stay unchanged (both 0)
# func (called from func2) will look in the global environment and find a = b = 0

x <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
a <- 0
b <- 0
func2(x)
a
b
```

**My question**

What environment should I use so that this works as desired, i.e. all variables are assigned to their name in the list, but only within the environment of the function where `walk` is called.?

Comment: There's a built in functions for this already called `?list2env`. Try that.

Comment: And you probably should be using `walk2(names(x), x, assign, envir = environment())` to avoid the relative environment by using an explicit one.

Comment: And one final thought is that it's usually not even necessary to do stuff like this if you use `with()` statement or something similar depending on the exact need. Auto generating variables usually leads to messy problems.